# Error When Source Artribute is Used in Frame Tag

Tags: xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open a webpage in Windows 8 XAML with the following Frame Tag.

```
<Frame
Source="http://medievaltvg.freeoda.com/"

/>
```

I get the following error from Visual Studio:

```
Unknown member 'Source' on element 'Frame.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you, that there is no member `Source` on the `Frame`-control.
This is not what `Windows.UI.Xaml.Frame` is intended for.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame).

```
You use the Frame control to support navigation to Page controls. You create
as many different pages as needed to present the content in your application
and then navigate to those pages from the frame. To navigate from the frame, 
you call the Navigate method and pass in the type of the page to navigate to. 
You can also pass in a parameter object to initialize the page to a particular state.
```

What you are looking for is the [`WebView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)-Control.